# Access denied on external storage: application not found

Tags: usb-host-mode, automotive-head-unit

I purchased an Android car head unit (K4811) and I cannot access a USB storage device that I plug in (32 GB, FAT32 or exFAT).

I think that this comes from the absence of a program allowing elevation of rights, because by downloading FileManager+, when I select the USB key, I obtain this message:
[image: Permission Settings]

But if I click "OK", I get the error "Application not found":
[image: Application not found]

I tried from the Google "Files" application, it shows me that I have to "Tap to give File access":
[image: Tap to give File access]

If I do, I get an "Access denied":
[image: Access denied]

If I click on the notification that appears when plugging in the USB key:
[image: USB key notification]

This opens the basic file explorer in which the USB key does not even appear.

Do you have any idea where this could come from? If an application allowing rights elevation is missing, is it possible to download it? I will be able to pass it by another means than a USB key.

My goal is to access the files on an external USB storage key.

### EDIT

The application has storage access rights according to Android settings:
[image: Android settings]

Comment: Go to settings > apps > permissions and set it per app. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9431959?hl=en

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sorry, I forgot to specify that the application does have storage access rights according to the Android settings.
The app works fine on internal storage, but not on USB.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thanks for your feedback, I edited the question to add precisely the goal that I want to achieve.